# Content Delivery: Remove expiry date of expired content via data loader

Tags: data-loader, content, content-delivery

From Winter '15 release, Content can be modified from API. the mass updated expiry dates of content delivery is possible using the object CotentDistribution and field EXPIRYDATE keeping the field PREFERENCESEXPIRES to TRUE.

However I need to remove the EXPIRY DATE of a Content that has already been **expired**. Currently if I set the PREFERENCESEXPIRES to false and remove the EXPIRY DATE, Data Loader says it has successfully updated the content but the change is not reflected on the record in Salesforce.

Hence, I'm unable to remove the expiry date but only able to set the EXPIRY DATE to a later future example 12/12/2999.

Any help on this will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data loader does not allow inserting null or empty values which explains why you are receiving 'success' but it is not reflected in Salesforce. 
To insert empty values in data loader, the setting 'Insert Null values' should be checked. 
In your csv file, set the value to an empty string

Comment: Yes!! Thank you. It worked I thought it was something to do the standard functionality of Content.